# Python Simple Cluster Computing / Multiprocessing on LAN?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, cluster-computing

I am trying to **implement a cluster computing solution with Python3** for the following problem: I have lots of raw data files on a NAS (>2TB, a few thousand files, each individual file can be processed in memory though, NAS performance is sufficiently high) and run some Python code on it to process the data and create an output file for each input file and store it also on the NAS.

Processing time is mainly constrained by the performance of the LAN (as a result of the fact that the NAS is located in a different building which is well-connected to our building, but the LAN inside our building only operates on 100Mbits) and to a smaller extend by the CPU. I have a few (4-5) Windows PCs (List of IPs) on the LAN that I would like to use for this purpose for a small and simple computing cluster. So far, I did this manually by grouping some files together and adjusting my script on every machine and it worked fine. **I would like to automate this step now, such that I start a process at the "master" pc, that creates a queue of tasks that performs the same code for each file (reading and writing from/to the network drive, probably using some "map" command), and allocates these tasks to the PCs in the cluster.** Hence,

- Every task can work independently and use its own environment. No communication between tasks/nodes needs to take place and no variables need to be shared.
- In especially, I don't want to have the results send back to the master PC, but only have the individual PCs write the results to the NAS.

Given my very limited experience in cluster computing/parallel processing, I would like to implement this as simple as possible. After some research, I am a little overwhelmed given the availability of modules/packages for example on this website: https://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing. A lot of packages seem to be either a total overkill to my problem or haven't been supported in years.

**If you could give me any recommendation on a good package for this purpose that would be highly appreciated. Is there a simple solution that I haven't come accross so far? Alternatively, would it in general be possible to solve this using standard packages such as threads, multiprocessing, queue, etc...? Is there any example code for a similar implementation somewhere?**

Additionally it would be nice to be able to do the following, although not required:

- Bonus1: Be able to use the "master" PC for computations as well.
- Bonus2: Run several instances on each PC. The number of instances would need to vary accross PCs though due to different Hardware set-ups.

Comment: Python is not the best option neither for big loads of data or to multithreading processing. But, if you absolutly need to use python, I would recommend to use Celery or RabbitMQ to stablish a task queue between nodes.

Comment: Also, this is a very interesting question. Please, update your message with your final solution once you have decided your architecture.

Comment: Thanks for the quick followup, from a first look it seems that RabbitMQ alone would be able to cover most of what I try to do, since Celery requires a message broker in any case, I might look at RabbitMQ in more detail first. I'll keep you posted about the progress.

Comment: Great, Good Luck :)